# Import BaseGameUtils in Android Studio with libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to integrate Google Play Games in a libgdx project.
All the tutorials found around the internet are either old or incorrect, also they're based on Eclipse.

My problem is that it seems like the BaseGameUtils module won't compile due to some incompatibility, which I'm not able to undestand.

The procedure I've followed is the standard one:

1) I've downloaded the BaseGameUtils module, available [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils)

2) I've imported it as a module in my project with File -> New -> Import Module...

3) I've added the dependency in my build.gradle (Module:android) as

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0'
    compile(':BaseGameUtils')
}
```

When I try to sync and build, I'm getting this error:

```
Error:(5, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library [my game path]\BaseGameUtils\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\20.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml
```

How can I fix that? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: The error suggests that you have a smaller sdk version decalred than the one your library supports. Try modifying the `minSdkVersion` on your `Gradle` file so that it matches the one your library requires.

Comment: It seems like it's working, I actually had to write the min-sdk version in the manifest too, it was already present in the gradle, thank you by the way, you hinted me the right way, you can write the correct answer if you want, I'll accept it.

Comment: done :) glad it helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests that you have a smaller *sdk* version decalred than the one your library supports.

Try modifying the `minSdkVersion` on your Gradle file so that it matches the one your library requires. (In your case 7).